# Send command to a nohup process?

Tags: linux, command-line, background-process, nohup

I have a minecraft server that when I run it, takes the console and can receive commands/parameters.

I'm running it with `nohup java -Xms.... -jar spigot.jar &`. It will stay in the background with PID XXXX and port YYYY.

I want know if it is possible to send commands to it as `/help`.

Regards and thanks for the help.

Comment: "Send command" how? Probably redirect it to read from a FIFO (socket or named pipe) if it's reading standard input.

Comment: Please provide code or the commands being run in the question.

Comment: Is a minecraft server, i'm runing it with "nohup java -Xms.... -jar spigot.jar &" and stay in background with PID XXXX and port YYYY, i want know if is possible send commands to it as "/help".

Comment: @tripleee thanks, this works  "nohup tail -f /usr/server/console.in | nohup java -Xms.... -jar spigot.jar >> /usr/server/console.out &" whit an "echo command >> /usr/server/console.in" is as i run the command in the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can solved this by tripleee.

This works "nohup tail -f /usr/server/console.in | nohup java -Xms.... -jar spigot.jar >> /usr/server/console.out &"

Whit"echo command >> /usr/server/console.in"

Is as i run the command in the server.

Comment: "For" me? You mean more like with my hints.

Comment: My english isn't so good as you can see. The problem of try write fast xP

Comment: two things I found with this solution: remove the slash from your command "help" not "/help" and you need to rewrite the file rather than append it `echo 'help' > /usr/server/console.in`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of running your server in the background with `nohup java -Xms.... -jar spigot.jar &` you could use a terminal multiplexer like `screen`.
See https://ss64.com/bash/screen.html
or https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html

For interactive start, run `screen` first, then inside the `screen` session run `java -Xms.... -jar spigot.jar` (in the foreground, without `nohup` or `&`).
Then you can use `screen`'s escape sequence <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> to detach from the session. Your server will continue to run.

If you later want to interact with the server, use `screen -r`. This will reattach your terminal to the session.
Type `/help` or whatever you need to do. 
When you are done, detach from the session again.

You could also use `screen -d -m java -Xms.... -jar spigot.jar` to create a detached session with your command, e.g. in a startup script.

`screen` has a lot more capabilities. Read the documentation.

Comment: Hi, i use DISPLAY=1:0 because i'm runing an svn in the server, but usualy i use command line. But i solve this doubt with the tripleee idea. Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: @Inoku I don't understand how `DISPLAY=1:0` is related to my proposed solution. What display does `1:0` refer to? If this is a clarification of your question you should edit the question. If it is a new requirement or a related question, write a new question, maybe with a reference to this one.